# Tracing disk and memory usage on startup

Tags: windows-vista, boot, performance

I'm running on Vista Home Premium and running into some startup performance issue recently. It takes around 4 - 6 minutes from the moment I turn on the laptop Power to the Desktop ready to be used. I only have 4 startup programs running (ATKMedia, ATKHotkey, Symantec and Synaptic Driver). For services, I've already turned off Super Prefetch and Indexing.

After booting, I can use the laptop no problem (i.e. it's fast), but this slow bootup is bothering me.

Is there any tools out there that can help me tell where the bottleneck is on startup?

Thank's in advance for your responses (if any).

NB : I remember that there's a parameter in the registry if turned on, will verbosely output what file is being processed when the Windows is booting up, but I forgot what :(.

My Spec:
P8600 dual core @2.4MHz, 
4GB of RAM, 
5400 RPM HDD

Comment: Is it member of a domain? Perhaps it's trying to mount some network resource that's unavailable.

Comment: Oh interesting, how do I check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tool:

http://soluto.com/

Comment: Downloaded, and when installing it's stuck at installing .NET at 4%.

Comment: @andreas - Try installing .Net separately before installing the tool.

Comment: Installed and Run, but keep crashing :(, is it compatible with Vista?